# mysql_insert_id returning odd numbers?

Tags: php, mysql

I know it's depreciated, and not generally good practice.  But this command: **mysql_insert_id** for some reason is returning this weird number.  And it never has done before.

I cannot find reference to this number anywhere.  For instance, I just inserted a record into `id`:2, and it gives me the number 1587.

Where is getting that from?

I've had to resort to reverse-querying the database with the exact values that i've just pulled out of it to get the ID.  But this makes no sense.

**Edit**
Sorry if I didnt explain this; but it is just a standard insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO `job` (`subject`,`deadline`,`status`) VALUES ('$title','3454354','CREATED');
```

And the autoincrement is on the PK which is called 'id'.

The field `id` results in being set to `2`, but `mysql_insert_id` returns an odd number.
I ran a table status and it shows the auto_increment to be as expected.  I am not inserting anything else in this time.  Literraly straight after I insert it I am querying for the last inserted ID.

Comment: can you add more information, the code you have tried to use for example

Comment: Could it be a database corruption? Export all tables, delete database and import previously save data.

Comment: You didn't show us the query nor your database schema. What guarantees that there wasn't a trigger that did an insert as well and you got the ID because the trigger did the trigger invoked the last INSERT statement? If you want an answer based on the facts you provided - something else does the insert, and the id that was assigned to it was 1587.

Answer (score 0):

chceck `AUTOINCREMENT` col before inserting, and after

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM `db_name` WHERE NAME='col_name';
```

EDIT:
You can see in "create table" if You have huge start number.

Maybe You have Trigger on this table ?

Answer (score 0):

the manual says mysql_insert_id returns:

> The ID generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the previous query on
>   success, 0 if the    previous query does not generate an
>   AUTO_INCREMENT value, or FALSE if no MySQL connection was established.

do you have auto increment on?